# Adding signed Assembly to nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, assemblies

I'm working with nHibernate.

I have make an Assembly (ex : DAL.dll), which contains the mapping files (.hbm.xml) and the entities (.cs). This Assembly has a strong name (signed).

I created a console project, which reference the DAL assembly (DAL.dll).

When I try to instanciate the Configuration, it fails when loading my DAL Assembly.

The error is the following :

> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: DAL.Mappings.Cat.hbm.xml
>   NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class DAL.Cat, DAL not found

This is the console application code :

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver");
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, dsn);
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(MsSql2005Dialect).AssemblyQualifiedName);
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true");
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionProvider, typeof(DriverConnectionProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName);
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(DAL).Assembly);
```

The problem is that the hbm.xml files are referencing the entities like that :

```
<class name="DAL.Cat,DAL">
```

Is there another solution than referencing each class with their full name (with the key, etc.)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly cleaner way of specifying the mappings that can help you is:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="DAL"
                   assembly="DAL assembly fully qualified name">
  <class name="Cat">
  ...
```

However, this should work even if the assembly name is not qualified. Try different combinations and see what happens.

Comment: That's exactly what I expect ! Thanks a lot.